# console info not stepping ahead of "Starting Activity"

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
[2013-11-16 09:26:43 - Emulator] emulator: Open HAX device failed
[2013-11-16 09:26:43 - Emulator] 
[2013-11-16 09:26:43 - Emulator] HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
[2013-11-16 09:26:44 - Desk App] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2013-11-16 09:26:44 - Desk App] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-11-16 09:29:43 - Desk App] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5556'
[2013-11-16 09:29:43 - Desk App] Uploading Desk App.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2013-11-16 09:29:43 - Desk App] Installing Desk App.apk...
[2013-11-16 09:30:47 - Desk App] Success!
[2013-11-16 09:30:47 - Desk App] Starting activity nil.android.DeskApp.DeskApp on device emulator-5556
```

Its not moving to next step, and open my application..
screen is not locked and also i am able to click on any shortcut in emulator...

Thanks in Advance.
Rgrds,
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you found “HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode” problem while running android SDK. This mean your computer CPU must be intel core and must support ***“Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager”***. **It means that you have configured the emulator in a way which is not supported by your operating system.**

In order to fix this HAX is not running issue, take the following steps:

1) Start AVD Manager
2) Select the emulator device on which you are working
3) Click Edit button
4) Choose the CPU/ABI as ARM(armeabi-v7a)
5) Click ok

The correct settings are shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

The above steps should solve your problem. Basically, we have changed the CPU type and chose a CPU which is compatible with Windows/Linux. If you had earlier chosen some other CPU for Android emulator then it shall try to use hardware acceleration which is not there in your underlying hardware. By changing the CPU/ABI field, you are no longer using the hardware acceleration. The advantage of running emulator with hardware acceleration improves the performance of the emulator on your machine.

For more information on hardware acceleration feature which was introduced in Android API level 17,[Read](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm)

**2) If changing the CPU type doesn’t work then you can try reducing the allocated memory to below 512MB.**

Hope this will help you.